# Is there any way to connect the Database server from Selenium ide?

Tags: database, oracle, testing, selenium-ide

I need to populate a text box with the results of the query from a database(oracle db) in one of my selenium ide test cases.is this possible? and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it is possible using selenium IDE, Have you considered using Selenium RC which provides full fledged capabilities of a programming languages including db connection.